# why the hidden state of rnn become almost -1 or 1 in training

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm doing a prediction task which `predict the shop people will click given the history click sequence of this customer`. I use rnn to model the data and padded the sequence to the maximum length of each batch. but when I run the program I found that the accuracy is 0.

To check the reason,  I print the hidden state of the rnn  and I found that at the begining the hidden state looks normal like below:

```
0.032015    -0.035735   -0.029594   0.005365    -0.071770   -0.025201   -0.004161   0.020350    0.039628    -0.007609   0.024006    -0.025892   -0.018199   -0.031058   0.030478    -0.021961   0.029184    0.029706    -0.029774   -0.006685
```

but gradually it becomes almost 1 and -1 like：

```
    1.000000    -0.682048   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   0.999937    -1.000000   1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    0.787266    -1.000000   -0.747823   -1.000000   -1.000000   -1.000000   0.999986    0.884828    -0.999983   1.000000
```

To be specific, the num of shop in the dataset is about `2 million` and the num of  sequence is about `20 million` and sequences whose length is below 5 or above 30 are filtered. The average sequence length is about `10`. For example, if a sequence is `3 5 7 10 22 58 6`, then the input of this sequence is `3 5 7 10 22 58` and the corresponding label is `5 7 10 22 58 6`.

To save the time I use `sampled_softmax_loss` during training. And when prediction  I use the shop id occurred in the current batch to be the target classes. I know this would be problematic as some shops occur several times but I didn't know any other better method and I think it's not the main problem as the hidden state problem will make training failed and then even though I use the perfect way (full softmax ? ) to predict the accuracy will still be poor.

Now I don't know why the hidden state becomes almost 1 and -1 and what to do to fix this to make the accuracy acceptable.

Would anyone  give some suggestions?

There may be some other problems with my program and my method to do this task, if so please let me know.

Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Thanks advance!

my simplified model definition is below and I omitted the training and predcition part.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops import rnn_cell
import tensorflow as tf

n_steps = 3
n_inputs = 3
n_neurons = 5
class_num = 20 
batch_size = 4
max_length= 30

tf.reset_default_graph()
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, n_steps])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, n_steps], name='output')
seq_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0.0, 0.1)
embedding = tf.get_variable('embedding', [class_num , n_inputs], initializer=initializer)
softmax_W = tf.get_variable('softmax_w', [class_num , n_neurons], initializer=initializer)
softmax_b = tf.get_variable('softmax_b', [class_num], initializer=initializer)

inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, X)

basic_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons)

stacked_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell( [basic_cell]*2)

init_state = stacked_cell.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(stacked_cell, inputs, sequence_length=seq_length, initial_state = init_state,dtype=tf.float32)

output_reshaped = tf.reshape(outputs, [ -1, n_neurons ] )

#generate sequence mask to omit the loss of the padded position of the sequence.
lower_triangular_ones = tf.constant(np.tril(np.ones([max_length])),dtype=tf.int32)
seqlen_mask = tf.slice(tf.gather(lower_triangular_ones, seq_length - 1),[0, 0], [batch_size, tf.reduce_max(seq_length)])

seqlen_mask_reshaped = tf.reshape( seqlen_mask , [ -1] )

Y_reshaped = tf.reshape( Y, [-1,1 ] )

if task == 'train':
    cost_with_mask_sample = tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_W, 
                                                     biases=softmax_b, 
                                                     labels=Y_reshaped, 
                                                     inputs=output_reshaped ,
                                                     num_sampled=5,
                                                     num_classes=20, partition_strategy="div")

    pure_cost = cost_with_mask_sample * tf.cast(seqlen_mask_reshaped, tf.float32)

    cost = tf.reduce_sum( pure_cost ) / tf.reduce_sum( tf.cast(seqlen_mask_reshaped, tf.float32) )

elif task == 'evaluate':
#use shop occurred in the batch as target class as the full softmax is infeasible

    sampled_W = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(softmax_W, Y)
    sampled_b = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(softmax_b, Y)

    tmp_logits = tf.matmul(output_reshaped, tf.reshape(sampled_W, [-1, n_neurons]), transpose_b=True)
    logits = tmp_logits  + tf.reshape(sampled_b, [-1])
    preds = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    diag_preds = tf.diag_part(preds)
    unmasked_loss = -tf.log(diag_preds+1e-24)
    unmasked_loss_reshaped = tf.reshape( unmasked_loss , [-1] )
    masked_loss = unmasked_loss_reshaped * tf.cast(seqlen_mask_reshaped, tf.float32)
    predict_cost = tf.reduce_sum(masked_loss) / tf.reduce_sum( tf.cast(seqlen_mask_reshaped, tf.float32) )
    result = preds > tf.reshape(diag_preds, [-1,1])
    padded_ranks = tf.reduce_sum( tf.cast( result, tf.int32) , axis=1 )  + 1
    rank_ok = tf.cast(padded_ranks <20, tf.int32) * seqlen_mask_reshaped
    acc_ok = (padded_ranks == 1) * seqlen_mask_reshaped

#just to check the program 
X_batch = np.array([
  # t = 0      t = 1     t=2
  [2, 5, 8], # instance 0
  [3, 2, 0], # instance 1
  [7, 12,0], #instance 2
  [17,15,11], #instance 3
])

Y_batch = np.array([
     # t = 0      t = 1     t=2
  [5,8,10], # instance 0
  [2,0, 0], # instance 1
  [12, 0, 0 ], #instance 2
  [15, 11,0 ], #instance 3 

])
seq_length_batch = np.array([3, 2, 2, 3])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  outputs_val,softmax_W_val, sampled_W_val,sampled_b_val, tmp_logits_val, logits_val,preds_val,diag_preds_val,unmasked_loss_val, masked_loss_val,predict_cost_val,result_val,padded_ranks_val,rank_ok_val, acc_ok_val= sess.run([outputs, softmax_W,sampled_W, sampled_b, tmp_logits, logits, preds, diag_preds,unmasked_loss,masked_loss, predict_cost, result, padded_ranks, rank_ok, acc_ok], 
                                     feed_dict={X: X_batch, Y: Y_batch, seq_length: seq_length_batch})


  print('outputs:')
  print(outputs_val)
  print('softmax_W_val')
  print(softmax_W_val)
  print('\nsampled_W_val:')
  print(sampled_W_val)

  print('sampled_b_val')
  print( sampled_b_val)
  print('tmp_logits_val')
  print(tmp_logits_val)
 # print(states_val[1][0])
  print('logits_val:')
  print(logits_val)
  print('preds_val')
  print(preds_val)
  print('diag_preds_val')
  print(diag_preds_val)
  print('unmasked_loss_val')
  print(unmasked_loss_val)
  print('masked_loss_val')
  print(masked_loss_val)
  print('predict_cost_val')
  print(predict_cost_val)
  print('result_val')
  print(result_val)
  print('padded_ranks_val')
  print(padded_ranks_val)
  print('rank_ok_val')
  print(rank_ok_val)
  print('acc_ok_val')
  print(acc_ok_val)
```